# How to convert a list of strings to symbols in elisp

Tags: string, loops, emacs

The high-level goal is to use org-mode for handling package configuration using the pretty formatted lists which is passed in as a list of strings. `package-installed-p` and `package-install` both take symbols though.

i.e: with company installed

```
(if (package-installed-p 'company)
    (print "yes")
    (print "no"))
```

would output "yes"

Then from a string

```
(if (package-installed-p (intern "company"))
    (print "yes")
    (print "no"))
```

still outputs "yes"

It seems like I should be able to

```
(mapcar 'intern company)
```

to get a list of symbols defined from the strings in the list.
Instead, I get the error: 'Wrong type argument: stringp, ("company")'

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the string is wrapped inside a container.

```
(mapcar (lambda (x) (intern (car x))) packages)
```

appears to do the trick.